# Freshdesk feedback widget with Angular application

Tags: angular, freshdesk

I try to install [Freshdesk feedback widget](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/37690-getting-feedback-from-your-website-with-the-feedback-widget-) on Angular (version 8.2.7) application.

I have created widget embeded code using Freshdesk admin portal.

The widget code is here:

```
<script>
    window.fwSettings={
    'widget_id': <MY PERSONAL ID>
    };
    !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}() 
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/47000002937.js' async defer></script>
```

After I have inserted this code before `</body>` tag.

And this script damage my Angular application.

The error is here:

```
main.ts:12 Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
    at Function.assertZonePatched (zone-evergreen.js:52) [<root>]
    at new NgZone (core.js:39456) [<root>]
    at getNgZone (core.js:40707) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.js:40522) [<root>]
    at vendor.js:83613:31 [<root>]
    at widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/bootstrap.js:1:20208 [<root>]
```

How fix this error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-freshdesk-webwidget
any finding related to this npm lib?

Comment: I didn't see it. If you wish you can describe this comment as answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Freshdesk Angular wrapper.

It provided as [ngx-freshdesk-webwidget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-freshdesk-webwidget) NPM package.

Source code, documentation and examples are available [here](https://github.com/AlisonVilela/ngx-freshdesk-webwidget).